# Programmatically copy Azure databse to local machine and/or vice versa

Tags: .net, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

Is there a way to programmatically copy an Azure database to the local machine using strictly code?  For example I would like to create a function that when executed a copy of an Azure SQL database is replicated on the local machine and/or vice versa.  I have currently been trying to find a solution using .NET and SQL server localdb but have been unsuccessful.  Only ways I can find are done manually such as logging into the Azure portal and creating a bacpac file.

Comment: Did you try powershell ?

Answer (score 1):

I test it use [Microsoft Azure SQL Management Library **0.51.0-prerelease**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql/0.51.0-prerelease), it works correctly on my side.

Using `sqlManagementClient.ImportExport.Export(resourceGroup, azureSqlServer, azureSqlDatabase,exportRequestParameters)` to export the .**bacpac** file the **azure storage**, then we could **download** the blob to local  from the Azure storage. But we couldn't find `ImportExport` in the lastest version of **Microsoft Azure SQL Management Library SDK**. The **risk** is that we don't know when it will be **retired** by Microsoft. The following is my detail steps:

**Prerequisites:**

Registry an App in Azure AD and create service principle for it. More detail steps about how to registry app and get access token please refer to [document](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_stranger/2016/10/21/using-the-azure-arm-rest-apin-get-access-token/).

Steps:

1.Create a C# console Application

2.Get accessToken by using registry App in Azure AD

```
 private static string GetAccessToken(string tenantId,string clientId,string secretKey)
        {
            var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext($"https://login.windows.net/{tenantId}");
            var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, secretKey);
            var result = authenticationContext.AcquireToken("https://management.core.windows.net/",
                credential);

            if (result == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
            }

            var token = result.AccessToken;
            return token;
        }
```

3.Create Azure sqlManagementClient object

```
 SqlManagementClient sqlManagementClient = new SqlManagementClient(new TokenCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, GetAccessToken(tenantId, clientId, secretKey)));
```

4.Use sqlManagementClient.ImportExport.Export to export .dacpac file to azure storage

```
var export = sqlManagementClient.ImportExport.Export(resourceGroup, azureSqlServer, azureSqlDatabase,   
                    exportRequestParameters)
```

Export to Azure blob Code:

```
  var subscriptionId = "xxxxxxxx";
  var clientId = "xxxxxxxxx";
  var tenantId = "xxxxxxxx";
  var secretKey = "xxxxx";
  var azureSqlDatabase = "data base name";
  var resourceGroup = "Resource Group name";
  var azureSqlServer = "xxxxxxx"; //tomtestsqlserver 
  var adminLogin = "user";
  var adminPassword = "password";
  var storageKey = "storage key";
  var storageAccount = "storage account";
  var baseStorageUri = $"https://{storageAccount}.blob.core.windows.net/myblobcontainer/";//with container name endwith "/"
  var backName = azureSqlDatabase + "-" + $"{DateTime.UtcNow:yyyyMMddHHmm}" + ".bacpac";  //back up sql file name
  var backupUrl = baseStorageUri + backName;
  ImportExportOperationStatusResponse exportStatus = new ImportExportOperationStatusResponse();
  try
    {
        ExportRequestParameters exportRequestParameters = new ExportRequestParameters
        {
             AdministratorLogin = adminLogin,
             AdministratorLoginPassword = adminPassword,
             StorageKey = storageKey,
             StorageKeyType = "StorageAccessKey",
             StorageUri = new Uri(backupUrl)
         };

    sqlManagementClient sqlManagementClient = new SqlManagementClient(new TokenCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, GetAccessToken(tenantId, clientId, secretKey)));
    var export = sqlManagementClient.ImportExport.Export(resourceGroup, azureSqlServer, azureSqlDatabase,
                    exportRequestParameters); //do export operation

    while (exportStatus.Status != OperationStatus.Succeeded) // until operation successed
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60);
        exportStatus = sqlManagementClient.ImportExport.GetImportExportOperationStatus(export.OperationStatusLink);
     }

     Console.WriteLine($"Export DataBase {azureSqlDatabase} to Storage {storageAccount} Succesfully");
     }

     catch (Exception exception)
     {

        //todo

      }
```

[image]

We could get downloading the blob code from azure [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs):

```
// Retrieve storage account from connection string.
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

// Create the blob client.
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

// Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");

// Retrieve reference to a blob
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("blob name");

// Save blob contents to a file.
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"path\myfile"))
{
    blockBlob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
}
```

packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Hyak.Common" version="1.0.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Common" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Common.Authentication" version="1.7.0-preview" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Common.Dependencies" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql" version="0.51.0-prerelease" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.9" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Async" version="1.0.168" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.14" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="2.18.206251556" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.22" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication" version="2.0.1-preview" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Comment: These seems to be the answer I am looking for.  Thank you for your response @Tom Sun